# In localStorage how do we save similar tuples with index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, local-storage

In our extension, we are getting values of username( eg: Johnny123), accname (eg: Facebook).
I want to store this for multiple accounts and usernames in the localStorage.

We have written this code :

```
var i = Number(localStorage.usercounter);   // counter for number of users
localStorage.username(i) = username.value; // textbox value
localStorage.accname(i) = accname.value; // textbox value
```

this code is not executing, what is the right way to store the values?

```
localStorage.username = username.value;
localStorage.accname = accname.value;
```

this is executing and allowing us to retrieve values. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` stores strings on data-properties...

...your options are:

1. store a JSON representation of an array which contains user objects

   ```
   var userdata = [{ name : "Bob",  account : "Facebook" },
                   { name : "Doug", account : "LinkedIn" }],

   userjson = JSON.stringify(userdata);

   localStorage.setItem("users", userjson);

   console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users")[0].name);
   ```
2. store a JSON/string representation to a suffixed key

   ```
   localStorage.setItem("user_0_name",    "Bob"   );
   localStorage.setItem("user_0_account", "Tumblr");

   localStorage.setItem("user_1_name",    "Doug"   );
   localStorage.setItem("user_1_account", "MySpace");

   // ...
   ```

As you can see, the first option is the one that makes more sense.

Comment: I wrote a script to help with this. Its called truStorage, and it allows easy storage of objects, and arrays, as well as easy manipulation of these items when stored inside local storage. You can find it here https://github.com/andresgallo/truStorage. The api looks just like localStorage, but you don't need to stringify JSON, or any of that.

Comment: @AndresGallo might I instead suggest an event-friendly, CRUD-like ORM, which can keep an in-memory cache of your data, and only serialize/deserialize when you are actually saving something new, or are asking for a new chunk? Not that it isn't great to have something which automatically does your JSON-conversion and grabbing things by name, but there are lots of ways to skin this particular cat, and I think that for the upfront cost of a larger library (but maybe only 2x the size), you can have something which could look ActiveRecord, tie into REST, *and* speed up saving/retrieving.

Comment: @Norguard will var userdata overwrite previous entries everytime?
And how do i retrieve data?

Comment: @AndresGallo in truStorage, can i write it as

`truStorage.setItem('username.i',username.value);`
`truStorage.setItem('accname.i',accname.value);`

and to retrieve

`truStorage.getItem('username.i');`
`truStorage.getItem('accname.i');`

Comment: @SudhanshuSane Yes. It will.  That is why you need to JSON.parse, save the new value, and JSON.stringify the result every time...  ...or write an interface around it. `localStorage` saves a string to a value.  So if you need to save JSON, then you need to save the whole JSON string every time you make a change to it. You can build or use any wrapper/interface you want, but for it to work, it needs to save the whole JSON string to localStorage every time any property is changed.

Comment: @SudhanshuSane truStorage will work as you suggested, to write and retrieve. Do keep in mind however that just like real js objects you need to have username be an object. If you are using the version with modifiers you can even use javascript native methods like push, shift, unshift... (for arrays).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd read write it using truStorage (https://github.com/andresgallo/truStorage)

```
truStorage.setItem('a',{});//This will be the main key, the one localStorage is aware of

truStorage.setItem('a.b',[1,2,3]);//Now we can store variable 'b' inside object a

truStorage.getItem('a'); //returns entire object {a : {b: [1,2,3]}}
truStorage.getItem('a.b') //returns child object {b: [1,2,3]}
```

You can write directly to child items the same way as you suggested.

```
truStorage.setItem('a.b.c', 'value of third level nested object c');
```

In the background this really does the JSON parse/stringify and recursion for you, which will clean up you application massively if you are using lots of localStorage.

Comment: Also thought id add. Before creating the parent key, 'a' in the example above, check if it is already an object first, or you could end up deleting it.